Why is the search field in System Settings returning no results after updating to macOS 15 Sequoia?
I have an M3 Max 16" MacBook Pro. I updated it to macOS 15.1 (from 14.7) yesterday evening.
The search bar in System Settings is no longer returning any result after updating. Typing anything in it returns the message "No Results".
.
Do you know what may have caused this and what could be the cure?
On Apple Discussions there is someone who has solved it by deleting and restoring the User, apparently advised by Apple Support, but I am not going to do that.
What is the process governing this search? Perhaps there is some indexing still to be done?

Here is what solved the issue, thanks to a kind user of the MacRumors forum.
Here's the process:

Create a new administrator user.
Log-out of current user
Log-in to new user and complete setup, including (important!) logging into your Apple Account.
Inside the new user, verify that System Settings search works as expected—it may take a while and for me it was unresponsive or exhibiting erratic behaviour for a few minutes.
When you are sure that everything works, log-out of current user and log-in to main user.
Verify that System Settings search now works.

If that is the case, as it was for me, delete the extra user account.
I also suggest quitting System Settings, waiting a few seconds, and relaunching it. Before that, it was not recognising my computer as belonging to my Apple Account.

That's a nice machine you have there.
There is another fix on Apple Discussions which isn't quite as drastic, it involves moving out of the way the System Settings plist file or its cache file.
I've updated those instructions to use Terminal, as it's simpler, and integrated a second fix from the same page.
Source: System preference search not working on Apple Discussions
Instructions
Make sure your Mac is backed up.
Quit System Preferences.
Open a Terminal session
type:
mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist ~/Desktop

Restart the computer, open the System Settings, and make a search.
a) If search works okay
Delete the plist from the desktop.
b) If the application is the same
Return the .plist to where you got it from, overwriting the newer one.
Rinse and repeat the process with:
mv Library/Caches/com.apple.preferencepanes.usercache ~/Desktop

Let us know how you get on.

Question before I try: will this trash all my settings so that I have to reset each one of them from scratch?

I shall check and report back

I moved the com.apple.systempreferences.plist to Deskop and rebooted.
My System Preferences looks the same, all the settings are present.
That particular Mac is running Sequoia 15.0.1.

Thank you for your time and effort. Neither of these had any effect. I also tried to boot in Safe Mode, and was able to reproduce the issue in there. I am not sure if I have any other option left before calling Apple Support.

Sorry to hear that.  It's interesting that the problem is consistent in Safe Mode.  You may have uncovered a new bug.

I haven't got enough reputation to upvote and/or comment on your new post below with the solution - well found!  Glad to hear you're now sorted @NotationMaster

I was about to create a new user as described above when the 15.1.1 update came out. Installing that fixed the issue. I doubt there was a bug fix in 15.1.1, but something in the installer got things indexed again.
If it happens again I would probably just re-run the latest macOS installer from mrmacintosh.com rather than messing with creating users.
